# Access denied, error pushing image: failed to push to destination asia.gcr.io

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

[image: Error Image]

I am facing this issue when I am deploy nodejs app to google cloud app engine. It was working fine before but now it is showing this error.

Comment: In the log I could see "Access Denied" so at first glance it looks like an issue with IAM permissions. However there is not much information to troubleshoot. Please add logs, the permissions of the account that makes the deploy and the changes you made recently if any.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to IAM & Admin in your Google cloud console.
2. Click on Add Role
3. Choose your member currently pushing the image.
4. Set role to App Engine Admin